# PHP8環境にてxhguiをcomposer installした際にエラー

Tags: php, composer

PHP8.0.2でxhguiをcomposerでインストールしようとするとエラーが出てしまいます。

```
$ composer install --no-dev

  [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]                                        
  Parse error on line 10:                                                 
  ...    "autoload-dev": {        "psr-4": {                              
  ----------------------^                                                 
  Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

構文的にも間違っていなそうですが、何か分かりますでしょうか？
PHP7.3.27の環境では問題なくインストールできることを確認しています。

xhgui

https://github.com/perftools/xhgui

composer.json（参考用：アップされてるファイルそのまま）

```
{
    "name": "perftools/xhgui",
    "description": "A web based interface for viewing profile data collected by XHProf",
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XHGui\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "XHGui\\Test\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2 || ^8.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
        "pimple/pimple": "^3.0",
        "slim/slim": "^2.6.3",
        "slim/views": "^0.1.0",
        "symfony/options-resolver": "^3.3",
        "twig/twig": "^1.26"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@phpunit-setup"
        ],
        "cover": "simple-phpunit --coverage-clover=unittest-coverage.clover",
        "openurl": "open http://xhgui.127.0.0.1.xip.io:8142",
        "phpunit-setup": "test $COMPOSER_DEV_MODE = 0 || simple-phpunit --version",
        "test": "simple-phpunit"
    }
}
```

Comment: XHGui の README には "PHP version 7.2 up to 7.3" と書かれているので、PHP8 には未対応なのではないでしょうか。

Comment: [このissue](https://github.com/perftools/xhgui/issues/278)をみても7.4も対応できていないようですね。

Comment: なるほど、確認してみると現状対応していなそうですね…。